# How to pass commands on Command propmt using C Program?

Tags: c, linux, command-prompt

I want to pass some commands from my C program, Here  is the sample program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

    FILE *ssh = popen("ssh user@192.168.170.155", "w");

    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();


    if(!ssh)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open pipe for output.\n");
    } 

    if (pid==0){

        fprintf(stdout, "Child process properly created.\n");
        fputs("user", ssh); 
        fputc('\n', ssh);   // enter key 
         _exit(0);
    }


    fprintf(stdout, "Exit from child process.\n");
    pclose(ssh); 

    return 0 ;

}
```

Now when I run this program, it asks for Password at command prompt something like this :

```
user@192.168.170.155's password:
```

I want to pass password from my sample program, not from Command prompt.
Could anyone please tell me how to do this in C, programmatically.

SSH is used only for example.It could be for other scenarios also.

Thanks,
Yuvi

Comment: If your question is about `ssh` interface I suggest you ask in superuser.com.

Comment: No that it not related to sssh

Comment: No that is it not merely related to ssh, I have taken ssh as an example only. There are many cases when you fire any command using system function, then it asks for some argument.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `ssh` command reads the password from its `stdin`, in which case you'll need to pipe the password into the program, and for this you can use [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/popen.html). C99/POSIX example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *ssh = popen("ssh user@host", "w");

    fputs("p4ssw0rd", ssh);
    fputc('\n', ssh); // enter key

    pclose(ssh);
}
```

Untested. You may have better luck using a combination of `fork`/`exec`/`dup` etc.

Comment: I have updated my code, but still no luck. Cud you plz explain tad more how to achieve it, I am noob in C programming.

Comment: I have also tried all the permutation with the combination of `fork/exec/dup` here is the refernece link which I have followed http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/index.html, but still not able to achieve this.

Comment: @Yuvi: You shouldn't need to fork. What happens if you run the code above in my answer without forking?

Comment: It's asking for password just like simple `system()` call.

Comment: @Yuvi: OK, I found out that SSH detects whether its `stdin` is connected to a terminal or from a pipe, and if it is connected to a pipe then it doesn't read any data from it. If you replace `ssh user@host` with just `cat`, you will see that you pipe text into the `cat` command and `cat` will echo it to the terminal (or rather, to its `stdout`). SSH can't be scripted like this unfortunately, and this can be proven by using shell built-ins, e.g. `echo "password" | ssh user@host` doesn't work either, it still asks for the password.

Comment: @Yuvi: On my system, I get a warning from SSH when `stdin` is not connected to a terminal: "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."

Comment: I am not getting any warning like you have said. I have Linux 10.04 x86_64 machine. So is there any solution for this or not, like Aaron Digulla said earlier possible using `fork` and `exec*` calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but takes a lot more code. First of all, you need to use `fork()` instead of `system()` plus one of the `exec*()` calls to replace the child process with the command you want to run.

For details, ask here or see [Unix Programming Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_toc.html), specifically [1. Process Control](http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_2.html#SEC2) and [1.5 How can a parent and child process communicate?](http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_2.html#SEC12)

Comment: He also wants to "enter the password" though (I think) so this will require some file descriptor fiddling as well.

Answer (score 0):

When it's ssh a lot simpliar to setup ssh keys so you don't have to add an password. However if you really want to do that it's very easy to do with an api named expect. I have been using that myself with good results.

Comment: Would you please edit your answer to add information about the api you have mentioned?